# Probability of answering 4 correct answers out of 5 questions where one random question does not count

Tags: probability

I have a test of $n>1$ multiple choice questions (of $k$ number of choices, of which only one is correct) and the test has $m$ random questions that does not count to the final score, either if I answer them correctly or not. I want to calculate the probability of obtaining full score given that I don't know which (of the $n$) questions are the $m$ questions that does not count. So I want perfect score answering randomly to the questions, and the only thing that I know is that there are $m$ random questions that doesn't have any impact on the score.

I was thinking that it was a simple binomial question, but I'm not sure if I understand this problem correctly. My approach was calculating
$$\binom{n}{m}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^{n-m}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^n$$
but it could also be
$$\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^{n-m}$$

Which of these is the correct answer? And if any of those is the correct answer, what should I consider?

Comment: Why would you think it could also be $(\frac{1}{k})^{n-1}$? I feel this part needs a bit more clarification.

Comment: @TobyMak sorry, it was $n-m$ instead of $n-1$, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1):

You get a perfect score iff you answer all the questions that actually count correctly, which has a probability of $1/k^{n-m}$.

Comment: so it doesn't matter if I don't know which $m$ of the $n$ questions are those that doesn't count, the probability would be the same as if there wasn't such $m$ questions at all?